# Select duplicate rows in multiple columns of a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 4 columns, i would like to select the rows for columns 1, 2 and 3 have same data.

```
TableName
Col1  Col2  Col3   Col4
abc   12    xyz     1
abc   12    xyz     2
abc   12    xyz     3
abc   12    xyz     4
def   34    wxy     5
ghi   45    uvw     6
ghi   45    uvw     7
ijk   45    tuv     8
```

I'm expecting to select the rows 1 to 4 and 6,7

Thanks.

Comment: [Here's a sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37c04) you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get just lists of such values:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from tablename
group by col1, col2, col3
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you want the actual rows, then join this back in:

```
select tn.*
from tablename tn join
     (select col1, col2, col3
      from tablename
      group by col1, col2, col3
      having count(*) > 1
     ) tncol
     on tn.col1 = tncol.col1 and tn.col2 = tncol.col2 and tn.col3 = tncol.col3;
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way of doing it is as follows.

```
select distinct t1.* 
from TableName t1
left join TableName t2
on t1.Col4 <> t2.Col4 and t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 and t1.Col2 = t2.Col2 and t1.Col3 = t2.Col3 
where
t2.Col4 is not null
```

This is not very optimal though (if your table has lots of rows and lots of duplicates).